# Python Selenium driver.get() not working within a for loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The code below logs into a YouTube account, and once logged in, it should visit a few YouTube videos.

The issue is:

- If I do a simple direct link like here, it works

  `driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFDDN1C1MEQ')`
- If I do a loop to visit multiple links i get an error:

  `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)`

  `InvalidArgumentException: invalid type: sequence, expected a string at line 1 column 8`

the full code is below

```
import time
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def youtube_login():
    
    email = 'email@email.com'
    password = 'emailPassword'
    
        # Browser
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fhl%3Den%26feature%3Dsign_in_button%26app%3Ddesktop%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26next%3D%252F&uilel=3&passive=true&service=youtube#identifier')
    
        # log in
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('CwaK9').click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "identity-prompt-confirm-button")))
    driver.find_element_by_id('identity-prompt-confirm-button').click()
    
    #driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFDDN1C1MEQ')  # If I do a simple direct link like here, it works
    
    urls = []
        
    # You can add in a file and import from there
    
    inp = open ("urls.txt","r")
    for line in inp.readlines():
        urls.append(line.split())
    
    for url in urls:        
        driver.get(url)
    
youtube_login()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have bad URL format in `urls.txt`

Try to debug URL like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException

for url in urls:
    try:        
       driver.get(url)
    except InvalidArgumentException:
       print(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this with import time, time.sleep(0.5) before driver.get().